# Wrong date format in Java

Tags: java, mysql, date

ReviewTime: `03-11-2015 01:59`
for this one I am using the `dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm` format.
When I insert into the database it inserts as `0009-05-07 01:59:00.`

I am passing the ReviewTime in `formatDate(csvReviewContent.getReviewTime())`
after that I'm getting the wrong format...

```
Tue May 07 01:59:00 IST 9 .
```

Follows the code I am using for formatdate.

```
public static Date formatDate(String dateString){
        String[] dateFormats = MessageBundleUtil.getMessageResourceString("config", "csv.date.format", null, Locale.ENGLISH).split("\\|");

        try {
            if(dateString != null){
                Date date = org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils.parseDate(dateString, dateFormats);
                return date;
            }else{
                return null;
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return null;
        }
```

Please help me find a solution for this.

Comment: I think the error is in reading and splitting the date format string from the MessageBundle. Could additionally you post your MessageBundle file.

Comment: I don't see any code touching a database...

Comment: You should not store the date as text in you DB. You should store it as a date type